# Android. Обновление отключает сервис.

Tags: android

Есть приложение, которое включает сервис. Если обновить приложение, то сервис отключится. Возможно ли сделать так, что бы сервис не отключался?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, но вы можете отлавливать момент завершения обновления приложения и перезапускать сервис. Для этого объявите `BroadcastReceiver` для `ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED` в манифесте. Или же, на API >= 12 — `ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED`.